# Java GregorianCalendar

Tags: java, timezone

I'm trying to understand GregorianCalendar learning java as a seasoned Delphi (pascal) developer. According to the documentation, January 1, 1970 at 0:00:00 is the reference for calculating time elapsed in seconds from this point. So, in experimenting, I set a new variable

```
GregorianCalendar cal2 = new GregorianCalendar(1970, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0); //January=0, Day=1, Hour=0, Min=0, Sec=0
```

then I read the time

```
cal2.getTimeInMillis()
```

This should equal zero by definition. Yet I get 18,000,000 milliseconds. This is 5 hours. I am thinking this has to do with the time zone? Any suggestions, I am on Eastern Zone.

If so, how do I account for this? I am really trying to understand so I can calculate differences in seconds between two times. Without understanding this, I can't proceed!
Thanks!
Doug

Comment: "*calculating time elapsed in seconds*" actually, its the time elapsed in milliseconds

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.GregorianCalendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 & Java 9. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 2):

```
package so;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class BeginningOfTime {

  public static void main (final String[] args) {

    final Calendar localTZ = new GregorianCalendar (1970, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0);
    dump (localTZ);

    final Calendar utcTZ = new GregorianCalendar ();
    utcTZ.clear ();
    utcTZ.setTimeZone (TimeZone.getTimeZone ("UTC"));
    dump (utcTZ);
  }

  private static final void dump (final Calendar c) {

    System.out.printf ("%s: %d (offset %d)%n",
                       c.getTimeZone ().getDisplayName (),
                       c.getTimeInMillis (),
                       c.get (Calendar.ZONE_OFFSET));
  }
}
```

Yields this:

```
Eastern Standard Time: 18000000 (offset -18000000)
Coordinated Universal Time: 0 (offset 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

I know that this don't directly answers your question, but `GregorianCalendar` may not be the best approach here. I would recommend you to use a library like [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/index.html) since your are specifically looking for concepts such as [Duration](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/key_duration.html) and [Period](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/key_period.html). Also take a look at [ThreeTen](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/threeten/index.php?title=ThreeTen) the RI of [JSR 310](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), which is planned for [Java 8](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=337).

Here is a **JodaTime** solution to calculate time elapsed in seconds.

```
  DateTime start = new DateTime(2012, 3, 25, 0, 0, 0, 0);
  DateTime end = new DateTime(2012, 3, 26, 0, 0, 0, 0); 
  int seconds = Seconds.secondsBetween(start, end).getSeconds();
```

Answer (score 0):

I bet it is the Eastern Time Zone. The big question is: do you have to account for it? Are you going to calculate/record time in the same timezone? There's a lot of functionality into that class to where it gets to be very bloated, yet very handy.

The GregorianCalendar class does include time zone functionality and can also do things like give you the DST offset.

Answer (score 0):

## East coast of North America versus UTC

Your `GregorianCalendar` carries a time zone. But the definition of your [epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date)) is [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time). The first moment of 1970 on **east coast of North America comes five hours later** than the first moment of 1970 in UTC. So you are comparing apples to oranges.

Let's take another look, but use the modern *java.time* classes.

```
Instant instantEpochConstant = Instant.EPOCH ;  // Expect 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z.
```

> instantEpochConstant.toString(): 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z

```
Instant instantZeroMillis = Instant.ofEpochMilli( 0L ) ;  // Expect 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z.
```

> instantZeroMillis.toString(): 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z

```
long millisSinceEpoch = Instant.parse( "1970-01-01T00:00:00Z" ).toEpochMilli() ; // Expect zero.
```

> millisSinceEpoch.toString(): 0

In contrast, guessing your time zone is `America/New_York`, the first moment of 1970 *in that region* comes 5 hours (18,000,000 milliseconds) *later* than first moment of 1970 *in UTC*.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.of(
        LocalDate.of( 1970 , Month.JANUARY , 1 ) ,
        LocalTime.MIN ,
        ZoneId.of( "America/New_York" )
);
Instant instantFromNewYork = zdt.toInstant() ;
long epochMillisNewYork = instantFromNewYork.toEpochMilli() ;
```

> zdt.toString(): 1970-01-01T00:00-05:00[America/New_York]
>
> instantFromNewYork.toString(): 1970-01-01T05:00:00Z
>
> epochMillisNewYork: 18000000

5 * 60 * 60 * 1000 = 18,000,000 = five hours * 60 minutes/hour * 60 seconds/minute * 1,000 milliseconds/second

## java.time

The `GregorianCalendar` class is a flawed, poorly-designed, troublesome class. Avoid it. It is now replaced by `java.time.ZonedDateTime`.

### `Instant`

The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction).

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;
```

> instant.toString(): 2018-02-06T02:59:56.156787Z

### `ZonedDateTime`

You can adjust from UTC into a particular time zone. You will end up with the same moment, the same point on the timeline, but a different wall-clock time.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter pseudo-zones such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!). No such thing as "Eastern time", use a time zone such as `America/New_York`.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) ;
```

Apply to the `Instant` to get a `ZonedDateTime`.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

> zdt.toString(): 2018-02-06T03:59:56.156787+01:00[Africa/Tunis]

## Count from epoch

Handling your date-time values as a count from epoch reference date is ill-advised. Such integer numbers are impossible for human eyes to read as date-times, so debugging and spotting invalid values is difficult or impossible.

But if you insist, you can extract a count of milliseconds from the epoch of first moment of 1970 in UTC, 1970-01-01T00:00Z.

Beware of data loss. Any microseconds or nanoseconds in your `Instant` are ignored while generating this count in milliseconds.

```
long millisSinceEpoch = instant.toEpochMilli() ;
```

> 1517885996156

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).